# I want to Auto turn on/off the product, but don't know how. Can you help me?

Tags: magento2, product

I want to Auto turn on/off the product, but don't know how. Can you help me?

Comment: In which case you need to on/off product?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable the product with the qty.
So if the qty is below 0, the Magento system will hide the product in the frontend.

You have to update the settings in Admin
Admin->Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory.
And you have to also set the Manage Stock to Yes in the individual product.